# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED using Conan 2.0.4 and Python 3.9.13

Tags: c++, github, conan-2

I'm getting the following error when trying to download a file from github to compile from source using Conan 2.0.4:

[Error from Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpXoX.png)

```
ERROR: gtest/1.10.0: Error in source() method, line 104
get(self, **self.conan_data["sources"][self.version], strip_root=True)
ConanException: Error downloading file https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.10.0.tar.gz: 'HTTPSConnectionPool(host='codeload.github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /google/googletest/tar.gz/refs/tags/release-1.10.0 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)')))'
```

I checked my certifi package under pip and it is using version **2023.5.7**. What am I missing? Thanks!

I was able to reproduce this error on a RHEL 8.7 system (VM) and a Windows 10 system (local install). I'm expecting the package to download and compile from source on my OS of choice.

Comment: I clicked on this question expecting C++ code, but I don't see any.

Comment: Apologies, I will remove the c++ tag. I added it because it's a c++ package manager

Comment: My guess would be that you're behind some proxy server that's intercepting the https traffic. You'll either need to bypass the proxy or install it's certificate chain into conan

Comment: how do I get the certificate chain? is that something I have to talk with my local IT? or is it as easy as navigating to the website and exporting the chain from a browser?